# Auto Fill a Google Doc Template from Google Sheet Data

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs

In javascript I am total beginner.

For automation *(Google Sheets and Docs)*, I need to create a script that will replace the keywords in the target document with the contents of the table, which I did with great help from tutorials and instructions.

But I need the keyword to be deleted instead of a replacement if the cell from which the information is to be taken is empty. Ideally, the whole line on which the keyword is.

Will anyone help?

```js
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs');
  menu.addToUi();
}
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('DocAdress');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderAdress')
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('List 1')
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[8]) return;
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[2]} ${row[1]} - ${row[5]}` , destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    body.replaceText('{{firstname}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{lastname}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{bdate}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{adress}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{nuber}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{date}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{sig}}', row[7]);
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 9).setValue(url)
  })
}
```

Comment: Please add the code in the question, not with a image so we can copy/paste

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Please read first https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first.

Comment: Try using ````deleteRow(rowPosition)````, see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition).